# Error with getline (I believe), throwing std::logic_error when getting input for pipe program

Tags: c++, unix

I'm working on a homework assignment for my UNIX & Network Programming class where I have to rewrite the UNIX pipe (|) functionality.

I've tried multiple things like changing parts of my code to no avail and using GDB to try to debug the code, but it doesn't point me anywhere. I've done some error checking including exiting the program (the loop) if the user enters a null value, but this doesn't seem to have helped.

```
// Variable declarations.
char command1[255], command2[255];
char *tok1, *tok2;
string file_path;
int pipefd[2], rs;

// Loop indefinitely.
while(1) {
    // Get user input and store it.
        // command 1
    cout << "command1? ";
    cin.getline(command1, 255);
        // tokenize the command based on space as the delimiter
    tok1 = strtok(command1, " ");
        // if user typed quit, stop the loop.
    if((string)tok1 == "quit") break;
        // if user left field blank, error and stop the loop.
    if(tok1==NULL) { cerr << "pipe: Must enter a command.\n"; break; }
        // command 2
    cout << "command2? ";
    cin.getline(command1, 255);
        // tokenize the command based on space as the delimiter
    tok2 = strtok(command2, " ");
        // if user typed quit, stop the loop.
    if((string)tok2=="quit") break;
        // if user left field blank, error and stop the loop.
    if(tok2==NULL) { cerr << "pipe: Must enter a command.\n"; break; }
}
```

...loop ends after pipe and fork and all that is done, shortened to where I believe the problem is.

The following error keeps coming up and I'm at a loss for how to fix it.

> command1? ls
>
> command2? wc
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>
> what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Comment: Looks like the program tried to build a `std::string` from a null pointer. `strtok` returns NULL when it runs out of tokens or detects an error.

Comment: So that would mean command1/command2 is null at some point? I'm not sure how or why that would happen if I'm inputting the commands.

Comment: Your second `getline` reads into command2 when it should be reading into `command2`.

Comment: Oh wow. I don't know how I never noticed that. Thank you! Seems to have gotten rid of that error.

Comment: Hey, could I talk you into reading into `std::string` with `std::getline` and then parsing with a `std::istringstream`?  Something like `getline(cin, command1); istringstream strm(command1); strm >> tok1;`

Comment: You're right, I probably should be using the <string> version of getline.

Comment: Oh hey if you're using gdb here's a gdb debugging tip for C++ exceptions. Before running the program at the gdb prompt write `catch throw` that's like a breakpoint wherever exceptions are thrown. I believe you can also do `catch catch`.

Comment: And when it breaks at the exception you can type `bt` for backtrace.Then `up 3` to move up three frames and it would show you your `if ((string)tok2 == "quit")` line. And since there's only one string operation on there, bam, you know what's making the error.

Comment: Another gdb tip you may need to know is to make sure you compile with `-O0 -g` options to the compiler. That's "Optimization: none" and "debugging".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the second command, you are taking the first command as the input getline.

Change:

```
cin.getline(command2, 255);
// tokenize the command based on space as the delimiter
tok2 = strtok(command1, " ");
```

To:

```
cout << "command2? ";
// tokenize the command based on space as the delimiter
cin.getline(command2, 255);
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my null error. Funny how something you do by mistake becomes your biggest problem you can't seem to figure out.

Comment: I was glad I could help out!

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah the straight answer to your question is to move your `if( tok2 == NULL )` above your `(string)tok2` cast.

You are casting a char buffer into a std::string just so you can do a comparison.

So I assume that you are including the string header already. That means you have access to the getline that reads into a string. That is much easier to use and safer than char buffers. And then you'd already have a string.

Look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline and see override #2 and the example.

That will also fix your error here which is caused by strtok not finding a space, returning NULL, and you trying to make string out of a NULL pointer.

Comment: Thank you. I will work on that. I'm aware of and tried using both but for some reason the istream one made a bit more sense to me. I see what you mean though, and I'll probably change it.

Comment: @triglav Oh and instead of strtok to break on spaces you can just use `cin >> mystring` and it will break on whitespace while reading into `std::string mystring;` If you read a whole line first then you can create a istringstream to read from a string as if it was a stream.

Comment: @triglav I added a first paragraph which actually answers your question. :-)